# Does Scikit-learn release the python GIL?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I would like to train multiple one class SVMs in different threads.
Does anybody know if scikit's SVM releases the GIL?
I did not find any answers online.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, scikit-learn does not play any tricks with the GIL. Instead, it uses [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for all its parallelism, which spawns multiple processes to do its work. You can achieve what you want with a custom joblib `Parallel` construct.

If you intend to train multiple classifiers on the same dataset with different settings to find the optimal one, consider using the [`GridSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) class, which handles parallelism for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, unfortunately the problem is actually not solved since I need to rely on an external library for parallelism which uses different threads (for compatibility with other parts of a bigger application). Therefore I would like to find an alternative library for svm which releases the GIL .. or to trick scikits.learn to do that. Do you maybe have any suggestion?

Comment: You might want to run scikit-learn code in a subprocess. The classifiers it produces can be pickled, so you can transfer them between processes quite easily; the only problem would be transferring the training data in an efficient way (perhaps through the file system?).

Comment: Also the libsvm wrapper is written in [Cython](http://cython.org). I think it should be pretty straightforward to patch the wrapper code to [release the GIL](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#acquiring-and-releasing-the-gil). If you do so and that it solves your issue please submit your change as a pull request on github.

Also: be warned that scikit-learn estimators are not meant to be thread safe: use disctinct estimator instances across threads.

Comment: Also if you want to clone estimators to pass it around threads while isolating them you can use `from sklearn.base import clone` and then call `clone(estimator)`.

Answer (score 4):

Some sklearn Cython classes do release the GIL internally on performance critical sections, for instance the decision trees (used in random forests for instance) as of 0.15 (to be released early 2014) and the libsvm wrappers do.

This is not the general rule though. If you identify performance critical cython code in sklearn that could be changed to release the GIL please feel free to send a pull request.